# React Router v4 - Issue with Route render attribute

Tags: react-router

I am trying to generate a number of routes. The code does not throw an error nor any  warnings. This said, I can't seem to get my routes to work. None of the routes generated using `articles.map(...)` display anything when directed to. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. What am I missing? Here is the snippet of the code.

```
function App(props){
    const articles = [
        {id: 1, title: 'title #1', author: 'author #1', date: 'dd/mm/yyyy', post: 'post #1'},
        {id: 2, title: 'title #2', author: 'author #2', date: 'dd/mm/yyyy', post: 'post #2'},
        {id: 3, title: 'title #3', author: 'author #3', date: 'dd/mm/yyyy', post: 'post #3'},
        {id: 4, title: 'title #4', author: 'author #4', date: 'dd/mm/yyyy', post: 'post #4'},
        {id: 5, title: 'title #5', author: 'author #5', date: 'dd/mm/yyyy', post: 'post #5'}
    ];

    return (
        <Router>
            <div className='container'>
                <Navigation />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={ Login } /> 
                    <Route exact path='/signup' component={ Signup } />
                    <Route exact path='/about' component={ About } />
                    {
                        articles.map( entry => { 
                            let {id, title, author, date, post } = entry;

                            console.log(`/article/${id}`);
                            console.log(id, title, author, date, post);

                            <Route
                                 path={`/article/${id}`}
                                 render={
                                     props => <Article {...props} title={title} author={author} date={date} post={post}/>
                                 }  
                            />
                        })
                    }
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    ); 
}
```

Here is a link to the git [repository](https://github.com/edoroskevic/udacity-nano-project-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not returning the `<Route/>` component from your `map()` callback.

When you're defining a multi-statement `=>` arrow function (as is the case with the map callback in your code above), you need to explicity return the result via the `return` keyword in order for the arrow function to return something (ie each `<Route/>` component)

Try the following adjustment:

```
{
  articles.map( entry => { 
      let {id, title, author, date, post } = entry;

      console.log(`/article/${id}`);
      console.log(id, title, author, date, post);

      // [ UPDATE ] Add return before <Route
      return (<Route
            path={`/article/${id}`}
            render={
                props => <Article {...props} title={title} author={author} date={date} post={post}/>
            }  
      />)
  })
}
```

Also, ensure that webpack is configured so that the `bundle.js` is injected into your `index.html` file with an absolute path. This will ensure that it can be accessed when your app first loads from a nested routes.

You can achieve this by adding the following to the `output` configuration of `webpack.config.js`:

```
output: {
        filename: 'build.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build') , 

        publicPath:'/'  /* <-- Add this to inject bundle at absolute path */
},
```

Comment: Good point. I have tried to add return as you've suggested, it still does not display any of the routes when I navigate to them in the browser. The screen is just blank :s

Comment: Couple of diagnosis questions: 1. Can you render `<Article />` in isolation with mock props, and does it display anything? 2. If you replace `<Article />` with something like `<h1>test</h1>` do you see the heading at those routes? 3. Do your other hard-coded routes work (ie `/about`)?

Comment: I did test `<Article />` in isolation, and yes it does work. If I replace `<Article />` with arbitrary JSX - it also does not work. I think, the problem is with the path. All other routes work. All imports are also present. No errors or warnings. I spent last two hours with it now lol

Comment: Ouch, okay - can you inspect the `props` that your `<Route render={ props => .. }` />` passes to `<Article/>`, and do they look suspicious? What happens if you hard code a `<Route exact path='/test' render={ props => <Article {...props} title={'test'} author={'dacre'} date={'11/22/33'} post={'hello!'}/> }  />`, and does that work?

Comment: I can't examine `props` given `Route` does not resolve :s. I did edit the `<Article />` and removed all `props` to simplify the problem. This did not yield any results. I also tried to hard core a path e.g. `/article/1` but that also didn't work :s

Comment: I made a git repo containing all the code if you want to mess around with it to see if you can come to any sense with it. Your time is obviously appreciated

Comment: Having a look :-)

Comment: it was `webpack` ..., apparently one must specify a parameter `publicPath` to get it to work. Otherwise, it messes up the loading process. Ref. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/

Comment: Yes, I've literally just found the problem. As you say, it is a webpack config issue. I was able to get it working by adding: `output: {
  filename: 'build.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build') ,
  publicPath:'/'
 },`

Comment: please edit the answer and I will accept it. Your time is very much appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: @e.doroskevic just updated answer - you're welcome, happy I could be of some help. All the best with the project, it looks good so far :-)

Comment: again - your time is very appreciated :). Thanks, I am just doing it to learn React/Redux. I come from Angular. So, it's all a bit strange :D

Comment: Not a problem at all - I can relate somwhat, having come from angularjs a few years ago. It's a bit mind bending, but worth it imo :-)